# Sweave2Knitr Code

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I keep getting an error message when attempting to compile a pdf that reads:

```
It seems you are using the Sweave-specific syntax in line(s) 85; you may 
need Sweave2knitr("Filename.Rnw") to convert it to knitr. Running 
pdflatex.exe on File_Name_Update_FINAL.tex ...Running pdflatex.exe on 
File_Name_Update_FINAL.tex ...failed
```

I have checked my settings in tools>global options>sweave and they are set to

- Weave rnw files using: knitr
- And checked box in always enable Rnw concordance.

I have also unchecked and checked the enable concordance box.

I have attached the code below. It starts on line 85, the line of code with the error.

```
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

%\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The error seems very specific: "`you are using the Sweave-specific syntax in line(s) 85`". Can you show us line 85? The easiest solution would probably be to replace your Sweave-specific syntax with something `knitr` can handle without any conversion.

Comment: Also feel free to remove the commented-out options from your code in the question - they don't seem relevant at all.

Comment: Line 85 reads....'\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}'. Not really sure how to convert to knitr code. I'm new to writing code

Comment: Just delete that line.  `SweaveOpts` means "`Sweave` options".  You don't need it for `knitr`.